# Python mock iterator function inside a class

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, patch

I want to patch the `_iter_num()` function inside my `Num` class, so it can throw an error when it is called.
However, the following patch does not work.

```
# this_file.py
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
import pytest

class Num:
    def __init__(self):
        self.iter = self._iter_num()

    def _iter_num(self):
        yield 1

    def get_next(self):
        return next(self.iter)

@patch("this_file.Num._iter_num") # this_file is the filename.
def test_mock(mock_iterator):
    mock_iterator.__next__.side_effect = ValueError
    it = Num()
    # it.iter = MagicMock()
    # it.iter.__next__.side_effect = ValueError

    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        it.get_next()
```

```
# Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ValueError'>
```

When I directly set `self.iter` to a `MagicMock`, it works

```
# it.iter = MagicMock()
# it.iter.__next__.side_effect = ValueError
```

However,
since there are other functions in my code that reset `self.iter = self.iter_num()` besides `__init__`, I cannot just set the attribute without patching the `iter_num()` function.

Comment: @chepner Incorrect - the filename would be needed.  Without it mock would attempt to import a module called `Num`.

Comment: True; `patch.object` may be more appropriate, as we have a direct reference to the object being patched. `patch.object(Num, "_iter_num")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In init, the `self._iter_num()` is *called* and the returned value is assigned.

You're doing this:

```
mock_iterator.__next__.side_effect = ValueError
```

But you should do this:

```
mock_iterator.return_value.__next__.side_effect = ValueError
```

Comment: `return_value` makes sense to me but it still doesn't work. I have edited the question with your answer.

Comment: @HongruLiu It does work, and [here is the proof](https://repl.it/repls/WhirlwindOrderlyMemorypool).  Please don't edit the answer into the question, it invalidates the answers!

Comment: Thank you. Although I don't know why locally `python3.7 -m this_file.py` does not work after I save the changes but it works in my docker. Thank you..